# Fortran sgemm couldn't be found while building Eigen 3

Tags: cmake, fortran, eigen3, intel-mkl

I'm using Intel MKL for Eigen 3 on Windows. While making file, CMake found the BLAS library (which is Intel MKL Library), but it failed at the finding Fortran sgemm part. The error looked like this:

```
Try to find BLAS libraries: mkl_intel_lp64_dll;mkl_sequential_dll;mkl_core_dll
BLAS libs found for BLA_VENDOR All.Try to compile symbol sgemm with following libraries:;/Program Files (x86)/IntelSWTools/compilers_and_libraries_2018.3.210/windows/mkl/lib/intel64_win/mkl_intel_lp64_dll.lib;/Program Files (x86)/IntelSWTools/compilers_and_libraries_2018.3.210/windows/mkl/lib/intel64_win/mkl_sequential_dll.lib;/Program Files (x86)/IntelSWTools/compilers_and_libraries_2018.3.210/windows/mkl/lib/intel64_win/mkl_core_dll.lib;;;
-- Looking for Fortran sgemm
-- Looking for Fortran sgemm - not found
```

My command:

```
cmake .. -G "Visual Studio 15 2017 Win64" -DBLAS_VERBOSE=ON -DBLAS_DIR=my/blas/dir"
```

My cmake version is `3.11.3`

I've found Fortran `sgemm` in the internet, but I'm not sure what I'm going to do next, like where should I add the `sgemm` file or the performance will be dropped if I put the wrong `sgemm`. I'm pretty new with this and I don't want to use OpenBLAS.

Thanks for helping!

Comment: E.g., please specify the version of CMake you are using.  The `sgemm.f` file you probably found on the internet is very unlikely to provide the `sgemm` subroutine anywhere nearly as optimised as Intel MKL.  The attempt to look for `sgemm` may have to do with checking that BLAS libraries are available, the precise subroutine or subroutines you actually need may be different.  The set of libraries `mkl_intel_lp64_dll`, `mkl_sequential_dll` and `mkl_core_dll` should provide `sgemm`.

Comment: @VladimirF @ripero My command:

`cmake .. -G "Visual Studio 15 2017 Win64" -DBLAS_VERBOSE=ON -DBLAS_DIR=my/blas/dir"`

My cmake version is `3.11.3`

Comment: SGEMM should be provided by MKL, do not search for anything else.